# Must a service have a unique targetnamespace?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, soa

I'am wondering if two Web Services can have the same targetnamespace. Or is it discouraged to use the same tns multiple times and what is the reason for this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can have both the webservices have the same target namespace. But namespaces package logically related set of items together. I wonder why you would like to use the same namespace.

Comment: A customer uses the same tns for multiple versions of the same services. All the services are deployed at the same time.

Comment: So you are handling multiple versions of the same service by bringing up a new service for every new revision of the service. So how is client impacted by this way of versioning. I see he has to update his code to take advantage of the new features isn't it. Also look here for my earlier answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952910/web-services-versioning-and-server-side-handling/4141052#4141052